# Removing the root element using xslt

Tags: xslt

I have an xml schema that has a structure like

```
<Level>
<Level1>...data...</Level1>
<Level2>...data...</Level2>
.
.
.
</Level>
```

I want to remove the `<Level>` tag. How am I supposed to do that, with the help of xslt.

Comment: Then you'd be left with two root level elements; is that what you want?

Comment: I would want the structure to be like   <Level1>...data...</Level1><Level2>...data...</Level2>

Comment: Are you sure you want that?  Having multiple root elements in not valid XML.

Comment: @ freefaller...yes I am sure I want this

Answer (score 2):

The standard answer to any "how do I keep most of my XML the same but tweak some little bits of it" question is "use an identity template and then override it for the specific things you want to change"

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <!-- omit the <?xml?> line in the output, it won't be well-formed anyway -->
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but as Mr Lister points out in the comments, this will leave you with something that is not well formed XML, as it will have more than one document element.

When I apply this stylesheet on the input XML

```
<Level>
<Level1>...data...</Level1>
<Level2>...data...</Level2>
</Level>
```

it produces the result

```
<Level1>...data...</Level1>
<Level2>...data...</Level2>
```

Comment: Also, all the Level items, i.e., Level 1,2 etc...need to be assigned to a variable that is not unbounded...can that also be done through xslt?

Comment: @user1980193 Please clarify what you mean by "assigned to a variable that is not unbounded".  An XSLT typically produces XML.  It does not assign anything to variables outside of the XSLT.

Comment: I am trying a transformation, in which the target will be  string variable, that will hold all the Level1, 2 etc elements

Comment: So you want a string variable with the value `"<Level1>...data...</Level1><Level2>...data...</Level2>..."`?

Comment: @user1980193 it sounds like this is outside the scope of the XSLT transformation itself, rather it's to do with the way you are calling the XSLT from your other code.  For example if you're using `javax.xml.transform` in Java you could transform to a `StreamResult` that writes to a `StringWriter`.

Comment: @ Ian Roberts - to have more clarity, this xslt will be used in a bpel process..where the source would be with the Level tag and the target would be without the Level tag.

Comment: @user1980193 I don't know BPEL well enough to help with that, sorry.

Comment: @ Ian Roberts - can you just help me with removing the tag..rest can be managed...the solution given above does not work fine...is there any other way?

Comment: @user1980193 it works correctly for me, in what way is it failing for you?

Comment: 2 questions on this, the first being, that if I pass the structure as say <Level>
<Level1>...data...</Level1>
<Level1>...data...</Level1>
</Level>...what result is it suppose to give me? Is it that it picks only the data that is unique? If yes, then how does it determine the uniqueness.

Comment: second being, that what do "@*|node()" and "node()" represent?

Comment: @user1980193 q1: it gives back exactly what it was given to start with, but without the outermost element, which is exactly what the original question asked for. q2: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) has a good explanation of the XSLT identity transform. For more detail you should find a good XSLT tutorial and work through that.

Comment: @user1980193 if you have a different question about how to do de-duplication then please ask it as a separate SO question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store all child elements of the document element in a variable, you can do something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="myVar" select="/*/*"/>
```

If, however, you want to the stylesheet to produce a string, this might be a solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <!-- We write the opening tag -->
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',local-name())"/>
    <!-- Now, all attributes -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <!-- Depending on whether we have an empty element or not, 
         we're adding the content or closing it immediately -->
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="node()">
        <!-- Close opening tag -->
        <xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'"/>
        <!-- Add the content -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        <!-- Write closing tag -->
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/',local-name(),'&gt;')"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- Create empty element by closing tag immediately -->
        <xsl:value-of select="'/&gt;'"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*">
    <!-- Write an attribute -->
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',local-name(),'=&quot;',.,'&quot;')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It produces text (and therefore you won't get non-well-formed XML). It's a little over-simplified because it does not handle namespaces, comments, processing instructions and quotes in attributes. If your input XML contains any of these, you'd have to refine the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new XSLT definition which fulfill my requremtn with the help of your code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output encoding="utf-8" method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="nl">
    <xsl:text/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="tb">
    <xsl:text/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <!-- Open the root array -->
    <xsl:text>[{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
    <!-- Process all the child nodes of the root -->
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="detect" select="*">
        <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="$tb"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <!-- Close the root array -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$nl"/>
    <xsl:text>}]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*" mode="detect">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = name(current()) and name(following-sibling::*[1]) != name(current())">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="obj-content" select="."/>
            <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*[name() != name(current())]) > 0">, </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) = name(current())">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="obj-content" select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="name(following-sibling::*) = name(current())">, </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="following-sibling::*[1][name() = name(current())]">
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            <xsl:text>" : [</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="obj-content" select="."/>
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="count(./child::*) > 0 or count(@*) > 0">
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : [<xsl:apply-templates
                mode="obj-content" select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*) > 0">], </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="count(./child::*) = 0">
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*) > 0">, </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="*" mode="obj-content">
    <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="attr" select="@*"/>
    <xsl:if test="count(@*) > 0 and (count(child::*) > 0 or text())">, </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="detect" select="./*"/>
    <xsl:if test="count(child::*) = 0 and text() and not(@*)">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="count(child::*) = 0 and text() and @*">
        <xsl:text>: "</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">, </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*" mode="attr">
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node/@TEXT | text()" name="removeBreaks">
    <xsl:param name="pText" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText, '&#xa;'))">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$pText"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($pText, '&#xd;&#xa;'), ' ')"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="removeBreaks">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '&#xd;&#xa;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```